# Give headers margin-top unless they sit flush with container div?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have an online document that has two columns of body text (each paragraph in p tags), with a top-level `<h1>`/`<h2>` title and multiple inline `<h3>`'s.

The CSS I'm using to style the columns isn't relevant to my question, but the basic HTML is as follows:

```
<h1>Page</h1>
<h2>Article Title</h2>

<div.container><!--Begin container-->

  <div.col1>
    <h3>article heading level 2</h3>
    <p>Paragraph...</p>
    <h3>article heading level 2</h3>
  </div>

  <div.col2>
    <p>Paragraph...</p>
    <h3>article heading level 2</h3>
    <p>Paragraph...</p>
  </div>

...and so on

</div><!--End container-->
```

I would like to style my `<h3>` tags so that the tags at the top (i.e. the first `<h3>` of each column) sit flush with the top of the container, but the all other `<h3>` tags have a top-margin.

The end goal is to find an elegant CSS treatment that will give my `<h3>`'s greater vertical space (margin-top) than my paragraphs *without* me having to go through and add a custom selector to each `<h3>`.

I was hoping that there was some way I could use pseudo classes to this effect.

Comment: Update: Both answers (h3:not and h3 ~ h3) are perfect. Took a while before I could reply (sorry) but the solutions worked very well.

I ended up going with the pseudo-class only because my particular implementation ruled out using h3 ~ h3.

Thanks for the answers! Definitely opened my eyes to a world of useful CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `:not(:first-child)` to achieve this:

```
div.container > div > h3:not(:first-child) {
   margin-top:30px;
}
```

This will apply the styling to all `<h3>` elements which are not the first child as you wish.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/exB3J/2/)</kbd>

Please note that [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) isn't supported in IE8 and before.

If you happen to be using the jQuery library and would like for this selector (amongst support for various other pseudo-selectors) to work in IE8 and before, you could look into [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/).

Comment: Or use `h3 ~ h3` which is supported in IE8. (Not a pseudo-class, but eh, if the question insists on having one, `h3:first-child ~ h3` works too.)